# worklight 5.0.6 - Error when deploying apps to local server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have just upgrade my Eclipse client running Juno to Worklight 5.0.6 developer edition (5.0.6.20130311-0918)

The projects upgrade fine, but when building them and deploying to the local worklight server I get a constant 'persistency data access problem' This occurs across all of my projects and has only been seen since the update.

Any idea on what is causing this problem and how to solve?

I would add a screen shot of the issue but I am not allowed

Comment: What is your database setup? Has it changed between upgrades?

Comment: I am using the web SQL database in the app, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment - in 5.0.6, the database schema has changed, so you have missing tables now. In the Developer Edition of Worklight, upgrade is not supported (this is handled when purchasing a license and using the IBM Installation Mananger for installing Worklight).

Do you mean "HSQL"? What is "Web SQL?"
In any case you will need to clean your database so that it will be re-created, this time with the missing tables.

If you use the default database provided by Worklight (HSQL), go to your Eclipse Workspace and delete the WorklightServerHome folder. Then, re-build your application.

Comment: When I say web SQL, I am talking about http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ as in I am using database functions provided in HTML.

Comment: So I think we are talking about different things. I will try the fix and let you know

Comment: update- Scrapping my project and copying in the HTML files into a new project fixes the problem